# Redshift User managemt

Tags: amazon-redshift

Is there a way to restrict the user to view all the schemas in a database?
Scenario:

I have a database with multiple schemas. I need to give access to a user for a particular schema and it's tabled.

Even though I try revoking all the access to that particular user and PUBLIC group, still he can view all the schemas and its tables. (Only the data he can't view.

I tried below commands:

```
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA devops_test FROM testuser;
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA devops_test FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL on all tables IN SCHEMA devops_test FROM testuser;
```

Answer (score 0):

Once connected to database, users can read a list of all databases, schema's, tables, and even table columns in the cluster from the system tables, even if they are prevented from reading the data within those tables through the use of REVOKE ALL FROM.
 Try this:

```
REVOKE USAGE ON SCHEMA information_schema FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE USAGE ON SCHEMA pg_catalog FROM PUBLIC;    
REVOKE SELECT ON TABLE pg_catalog.pg_database FROM PUBLIC;
```

If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.